# Mysqladmin in mysql docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm new to the Docker business. I set up a nginx, php and mysql docker - now I would like to look at the mysql database. Is there a mysqladmin function or something so I don't have to write helpers from the start?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such funktion. But you can install mysqladmin in your docker.

It depends on the OS you are using for your docker image.
Insert something like `RUN apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Of course you can also install phpmyadmin on your real maschine and just connect to your docker container.